# Twitter card: summary vs summary_large_image

Tags: twitter, facebook-opengraph, meta, twitter-card

I read these 2 doc pages: [summary](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/overview/summary) and 
[summary-card-with-large-image](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/overview/summary-card-with-large-image), but I don't really see the difference.

Example:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />   <!-- or summary_large_image -->
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Small Island Developing States Photo Submission" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5510/14338202952_93595258ff_z.jpg" />
```

What is the actual difference betwen both at the end? The rendering looks identical:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 17):

You're quite right and I'll make a note to update these documentation pages. A summary card usually has a small image on the left of the text in the timeline - this variance in the docs may be the result of using embedded Tweets. Both examples in the documentation show what I'd expect a summary card with large image to render as.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. `A summary card usually has a small image on the left of the text in the timeline` can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Added an example from my test account on iOS

Comment: Why has their documentation still not been updated @AndyPiper? It is still showing as the poster mentioned with the screenshots

Comment: Unfortunately this has been low on our backlog, but we will get it resolved as soon as we can. Thanks and apologies.

Comment: @AndyPiper, Hi Andy, I wonder if we should have both summary card and summary card with large image? or how to selectively include? Thanks.

Comment: @Jun it is not possible for one page to have both sets of markup.

Comment: Hey @AndyPiper almost one year and still hasn't been fixed =3, if u need help to get it done I can send you my resume.

Comment: @andypiper Hello from August 2019, and this issue still isn't fixed.

Comment: 2021 and I've had to find clarification here too

Comment: 2022 and counting...

Comment: Summary Large Image requires a specific 2:1 image ratio. If the smaller images are not showing then it is likely there is an issue with the image size or access to the image URL.

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by @AndyPiper, this is probably a documentation problem. Here is the result of a `content="summary"`, screenshot from Twitter in Chrome browser (desktop):

[image]